# Sample program turns up files that aren't in Google Drive?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I just ran the sample program from Google listing all files in my Drive Folder (not on the computer but on the web service) Sample can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet).

Weird thing is though, the console output is showing a file that was previously there, but is not there any more. I can't really tell why that is. I made the file as a test in the past, then deleted it as another test. But alas the program show it as still there.

[image]

This file named "_meta" does no longer exist in my drive and haven't for more than 24 hours. So what gives?

Comment: read any meta-data info whether the file has been deleted or something. as you can still access deleted file from driver > bin/trash

Comment: @SiddharthPandey Oh..you are right. I assumed those wouldn't turn up haha. Thanks.

Comment: let me know if this works for you and I can convert this to answer. :P

Comment: @SiddharthPandey Sorry, you are right it works. Simply use the `file.Trashed != true` to filter on trashed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comment, read any meta-data information of this file whether the file has been deleted.

Google Drive allows you to access deleted file(s) from drive using its Bin similar to Recycle Bin concept on windows. So, a user may restore a file if needed.

You have discovered that `file.Trashed` is to be used for any query if you don't want the deleted files in your result.

Please change your condition to `file.Trashed == false` as it is easy to read compared to `file.Trashed != true`.